# Smart Contract to access to website

Tags: transactions, contract-deployment, browsers, access

We want to create a simple smart contract:
After the click of a "pay"-button, you have to pay automatically 0,01 ETH to our wallet and you can visit after the confirmend transaction a website/link/content.
Used Browser: Mist

Thank you for your help for us beginners to create our first smart contract.

Answer (score -1):

you don't need to creat a smart contract you could only using web3js send a transaction and check if it is confirmed then redirect the user to your link

Comment: Client side check s not enough to prevent users to access premium content. This has to be done on the server side.